# Implicit cast/number check produces 'unexpected X' JSLint error

Tags: javascript, jslint

this is nothing serious, but just a question out of curiosity. The following script in JSLINT.com gives a strange and 'unexpected' error. My script works, but I would still like to know if anyone can explain the error.

```
var hashVar = parseInt(location.hash.replace('#',''), 10);
if(hashVar-0 === hashVar){L();}
```

ERROR: Problem at line 3 character 4: Unexpected 'hashVar'.

Enjoy the weekend, Ulrik

Comment: What does hashVar-0 === hashVar have to mean?

Comment: This: `if ( x - 0 ) { foo(); }` generates the same type of error. It appears that JSLint does not like `x - 0` in the header of if statements...

Comment: Looks like it depends on the 0 , user Number(0) instead.

Comment: hashVar-0 === hashVar mean that hashvar is an int, literally.
109 - 0 = 109, lol - 0 != lol

Comment: @Ulrik parseInt() returns either an integer or NaN. Use isNaN() to determine if it's an integer or not.

Comment: @Ulrik M like I mentioned you wanted `+hashVar` instead of `hashVar-0` it does the same conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
var hashVar = parseInt(location.hash.replace('#', ''), 10);
if ( !isNaN(hashVar) ) { L(); }
```

This code has the same functionality as your original code.

---

BTW, this:

`if ( !isNaN(hashVar) ) { L(); }`

can be further reduced to this:

`isNaN(hashVar) || L();`

;-)

---

**Explanation:**

The return value of `parseInt` can be:

a) an integer numeric value
b) the `NaN` value

Therefore, if you want to test whether the return value is an integer or not, just use `isNaN()`.

Comment: Does work, but is there any reason why I would choose this way over the one I posted? Thanks btw.

Comment: Avoid the inbuild isNaN & and the inbuild parseInt there a pain with their edgecases. use `+` and `o !== o` for parseInt & isNaN instead.,

Comment: Edgecases? Explain please Raynos :)

Comment: @Ulrik You can use this tool: http://vidasp.net/string-to-number-conversion.html to help you understand the differences between parseInt and the + prefix operator. BTW, you have to use @ (like so @Šime) if you want the person to be notified of your reponse.

Comment: @SimeVidas there are a few quirks about the parseInt & isNaN implementation. `parseInt("0a") === 0` & `isNaN(null) === false`, `isNan(" ") === false`

Comment: @Raynos `parseInt('123abc', 10)` returns 123 and this is intentional - it is a known behavior. `isNaN` returns true only if the argument is indeed the `NaN` value. Any other value - like null or `' '` will produce false. This is how isNaN works.

Comment: @SimeVidas you would expect `null` or `' '` to be not a number. Since when are `null` and `' '` a number? Avoid them because the intentional known behaviour was badly designed. If isNaN is only supposed to return true for `NaN` then why is `isNaN("foobar") === true`. the inbuild isNaN function is horribly made and relies on type coercion. Avoid it. use either `+number` or `Number(number)` instead of `parseInt` aswell.

Comment: @Raynos `isNaN` is intended to be used with Number arguments only. Don't pass Strings or Booleans into it. `parseInt` always returns a Number value - therefore, it is safe to pass the result of `parseInt` into `isNaN`. parseInt & isNaN are not problematical. On the contrary, the + prefix is problematical becuase `+''` or `+' '` return `0`, so you have to guard against that.

Comment: @SimeVidas I see your point as long as the type of `number` is indeed `"number"` then your safe with `isNaN`. It gets dangerous if you stop using them together though. I see your point, I guess it's the users choice whether he wants to gaurd againts `+""` or `parseInt("0a")`